# 'No zip generators registered, folder output disabled' while trying to use zexmlss

Tags: excel, delphi, zip, openoffice-calc

I am trying to use zexmlss http://neborak.org/zexmlss/index.php?lang=en for export to Excel of ODS. I have compiled the library and I have included Synapse generator in the library. Now I am trying to use it from the code:

```
procedure Test;
var tz: TZEXMLSS;
begin
   tz := TZEXMLSS.Create(nil);

   tz.Sheets.Count:=2;
   tz.Sheets[0].Title:='Test';

   with tz.Sheets[0] do begin
      RowCount:=20;
      ColCount:=20;

      Cell[0, 0].Data := 'zexmlss';
   end;

   TZXMLSSave.From(tz).Save('C:\A_EXCEL\test.xlsx');
end
```

And I receive the error message 'No zip generators registered, folder output disabled'. Save to xml completes succesfully. How and where to register zip generators?

Answer (score 1):

Do you copy files from \delphizip\synzip\ to src folder (zipusesyn.pas, xlsxzipfunc.inc, xlsxzipfuncimpl.inc, xlsxzipuses.inc  etc)? If files present in scr folder use function SaveXmlssToXLSX() like:

```
//uses zexlsx;
procedure Test;
var tz: TZEXMLSS;
begin
 tz := TZEXMLSS.Create(nil);

 tz.Sheets.Count:=2;
 tz.Sheets[0].Title:='Test';

 with tz.Sheets[0] do begin
    RowCount:=20;
    ColCount:=20;
    Cell[0, 0].Data := 'zexmlss';
 end;

 SaveXmlssToXLSX(tz, 'C:\A_EXCEL\test.xlsx');
end
```